# Is it possible to make ng-if behave like ng-show/ng-hide using the same variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I've got a basic question which I can't find an answer to by looking at the Angular documentation or Google, so I'm assuming that this is not possible but I would like to know for sure.

Basically what I want is to use a variable, for example `$scope.loggedIn`, like this:

```
<div ng-if="loggedIn">Hide me when I'm logged in</div>
<div ng-if="loggedIn">Show me when I'm logged in</div>
```

So when this is true I want one `div` to show, and the other one to hide. I know this is possible when using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` but that doesn't remove them from the DOM which I would like in my own scenario.

One way to achieve this would be to use two separate variables of course but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can negate the variable with a `!`:

```
<div ng-if="!loggedIn">Hide me when I'm logged in</div>
<div ng-if="loggedIn">Show me when I'm logged in</div>
```

Comment: I'd sugest you to add some abstraction on this, by not exposing your loggedIn in the scope and, instead, using functions with clear names to show/hide based on scope state.: 
<div ng-if="show_when_not_logged()">Hide me when I'm logged in</div>